# Toolbar/aapbar image

Tags: java, android, xml

I have trying to place image on my app bar/toolbar but it is not working. I have searched this query over this site but didn't get a satisfactory answer.

My minimun SDK version is 15 and target SDK is 24.Really thankful if some one answers my query

This is my 
**menu_main** code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:aap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/sett"
            android:title="@string/set"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav"
            android:title="@string/butt"
            android:orderInCategory="200"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
            aap:showAsAction="always"/>
    </menu>
```

[image]
**This is my aap bar xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:aap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#C6FF00"
    aap:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**This is my activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.zaina.toolbar.MainActivity">
    <include android:id="@+id/aap_bar" layout="@layout/aap_bar"></include>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/aap_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you adding menu items into your Activity or Fragment?

Comment: If you want to add menu items `@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.your_menu_xml, menu);
    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}`

Comment: No i just want to display icon on aap bar here is is"android:icon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp""@firegloves@Charuka

Comment: you can add ImageView inside toolbar tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved because i did'nt add these lines of code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu item) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, item);
    return true;
}
```